# UICollectionView with UIWebView size problems

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to implement a `UICollectionView`. The cells I use have `UIWebViews` inside them. The main problem is I want to have the cells size be adapted to the actual content inside the webViews.

I used the following two methods:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCellDefault *cell = (CollectionViewCellDefault *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"rect %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.wvDisplayValue.frame));
        CGSize retval = cell.wvDisplayValue.frame.size;
        retval.height += 135;
        retval.width += 135;
        return retval;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CollectionViewCellDefault *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:detailColumnsCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSURL *indexFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    [cell.wvDisplayValue loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexFileURL]];
    cell.lblTitle.text = @"Description: ";
    cell.frame = cell.wvDisplayValue.frame;    
    return cell;

}
```

Problem is of course that the webView knows its size only once it has been loaded:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Is it somehow possible to adjust the size of a `UICollectionViewLayout` for a specific cell only once the webview has loaded its content?

Every example I found had either fixed sizes or didn't use webViews which need time until they have calculated their size to fit their content.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for the respective webView in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
CGRect frame = webView.frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
webView.frame = frame;
```

This will resize the webView to fit its contents. Then calculate the new layout and call invalidateLayout to use the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in WebView and CollectionView combination, and you are right, on one hand the collectionview need to determine the size of the cell first i.e. before displaying the collectionView itself i.e.

`- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

where as on the other hand the WebView can determine the actually size it requires only on `webViewDidFinishLoad:`

HOW TO SOLVE SUCH PROBLEMS ?

Well in my case, I had just one section which had webView in it so What I did is I calculated the size in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and then reloaded that particular section after it

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {

    if (!_isArticleLoaded) {

        CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        aWebView.frame = frame;
        CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        aWebView.frame = frame;

        NSMutableIndexSet *mutableIndexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
        [mutableIndexSet addIndex:2];

        NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

        _height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fittingSize.height];

        _isArticleLoaded = YES;

        [_collectionView reloadSections:mutableIndexSet];

    }

}
```

So initially, in `viewdidload:` the localVariables are assigned flowing values:

```
_isArticleLoaded = NO;

_height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0];
```

and for UICollectionView I had following:-

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width,[_height floatValue]+35);
    }
}
```

This had pretty much solved my problem, when I was dealing with one section.

In your case my friend, you shouldn't be using WebView for each and every cell, it will prove expensive